# Read XAML File and create elements

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I have an XAML file like this: (Snippet)

```
<DrawingGroup x:Name="DrawingLayer">
<DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
  <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,540.866,507.982" />
</DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
<DrawingGroup>
  <DrawingGroup x:Name="shape1_1" Transform="1,0,0,1,20.0093,-394.221">
    <DrawingGroup x:Name="shadow1_2" Transform="1,0,0,1,0.3456,1.9728">
      <GeometryDrawing>
        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5B9BD5" Opacity="0.22" />
        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
          <Pen Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Square" EndLineCap="Square" LineJoin="Miter">
            <Pen.Brush>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5B9BD5" Opacity="0.22" />
            </Pen.Brush>
          </Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="0,394.596,113.386,113.386" />
        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
      </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingGroup>
    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF5B9BD5">
      <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        <Pen Brush="#FFC8C8C8" Thickness="0.25" StartLineCap="Square" EndLineCap="Square" LineJoin="Miter" />
      </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
      <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="0,394.596,113.386,113.386" />
      </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
    </GeometryDrawing>
  </DrawingGroup>
```

Didn't format properly.

And i'm using a XAML Reader like this:

```
StreamReader mysr = new StreamReader("C:\\Drawing Bath Convert\\Test with connectors.xaml");
DependencyObject rootObject = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as DependencyObject;
```

which returns the object with children and i can go through for their children and so on to get to the geometry to create the elements at runtime.

i was wondering if anyone had a more efficient way to access each element within the XAML DrawingGroup?

thank;

Comment: your approch seems pretty straight forward ... plus it works

Comment: Thanks. it does work but i have many foreach's to get to the info and was wondering if there was a better way.